# Why my tooltip is not shown if I can see it in the source?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tooltip

I have written a small web page showing a graph but now I am having a problem with showing a tooltip. It is properly appended to the DOM but I cannot see it on the page.

```
 d3.selectAll("circle")
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .attr("r", circle_size_hover)
                .duration(transition_duration)
                .style("opacity", 1);

            d3.select(this)
                .append("div")
                    .attr("class", "mytooltip")
                    .text(d.alarms)
                    .transition()
                    .style("opacity", 1);

            console.log(d.alarms);
        });
```

After this I can see my div in the DOM:

```
<g class="circles">
    <circle cx="79.34074074074073" cy="113.50243902439024" r="7" style="opacity: 0.7;">
    <div class="mytooltip">51.28205128205128</div>
    </circle>
</g>
```

CSS:

```
.mytooltip {
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    width: 60px;                  
    height: 28px;                 
    padding: 2px;             
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background: lightsteelblue;   
    border: 0px;      
    border-radius: 8px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L42LU/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add html element to the body directly and position your tooltip as follows

```
d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class","tooltip")
                                .style("top",(d3.event.clientY - 10) + "px")
                                .style("left",(d3.event.clientX + 10) + "px")
                                .style("z-index", "10")
                                .style("visibility", "visible")
                                .text(d.alarms);
```

The above tooltip will be shown at mouse pointer position.
Again on mouseout event you can hide this tooltip by just changing the visibility style.

Tooltip CSS:

```
div.tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
        font: 12px Verdana;
        background: lightsteelblue;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

Comment: Although this will work the div will be placed in the global `<body>` tag (which is messy in my opinion - but I can still attach `<div>` with id `tooltips` to contain all tooltips.`

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid to insert HTML elements (such as a `<div>`) inside an SVG. You might be able to insert the tooltip as a `foreignObject` element in the SVG.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have just noticed that. Now I am appending `text` SVG element but it doesn't allow that much styling as html `div`.